# Python Pandas - Find the elements ( substring ) in the same column

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a string column ('b') and would like to get the strings which are like substring in the same column. Example, in the below dataframe column 'b' , world is a substring of helloworld and ness is a substring of greatness. I would like to get the strings world and ness in a list. Can you please suggest a solution.

```
     a           b
0  test       world
1  teat  helloworld
2   gor         bye
3   jhr   greatness
4   fre        ness
```

desired output in a list

```
listofsubstrings
Out[353]: ['world', 'ness']
```

Comment: you can use the method str.find(seach_str).  It returns a + number if found, -1 if not

Comment: I'm thinking you'll need to loop thru b and check to see if each value is a substring of another value in b (using something like @anonyXmous suggested).  That could take awhile by the way so hopefully your dataframe isn't too big

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create an array of truth values on wether the row index is a sub-string of the column header.

```
l = df.b.dropna().values  # grab values from b
# double comprehension
a = np.array([[j in i for i in l] for j in l])
# of course strings are sub-strings of themselves
# lets ignore them by making the diagonal `False`
np.fill_diagonal(a, False)

# find the indices where the array is `True`
i, j = np.where(a)

l[i].tolist()

['world', 'ness']
```

---

Even better imo

```
s = pd.Series(l[i], l[j])
s

helloworld    world
greatness      ness
dtype: object
```

Comment: When I execute line 'a = np.array([[j in i for i in l] for j in l])  ' I get the following error 'TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable' . I a using pandas version 0.12 if this helps

Comment: @Joe_12345 That's because you have `None` in your column `'b'`.  You should include it in your sample data as its an issue that needs to be addressed.  Otherwise, you're still asking questions like this.  However, doing this ought to fix it `l = df.b.dropna().values`

Comment: I am sorry you were right, it was my mistake of adding **None** accidentally when I re-created the DataFrame to test .

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
from itertools import product

#get unique values only
b = df.b.unique()
#create all combination
df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(product(b, b)), columns=['a', 'b'])
#filtering
df1 = df1[df1.apply(lambda x: x.a in x.b, axis=1) & (df1.a != df1.b)]
print (df1)
        a           b
1   world  helloworld
23   ness   greatness

print (df1.a.tolist())
['world', 'ness']
```

Alternative solution with cross join:

```
b = df.b.unique()
df['tmp'] = 1
df1 = pd.merge(df[['b','tmp']],df[['b','tmp']], on='tmp')
df1 = df1[df1.apply(lambda x: x.b_x in x.b_y, axis=1) & (df1.b_x != df1.b_y)]
print (df1)
      b_x  tmp         b_y
1   world    1  helloworld
23   ness    1   greatness

print (df1.b_x.tolist())
['world', 'ness']
```

Comment: Will this be an efficient if I have 40,000+ rows ?

Comment: I think no, because very complicated task :(

Comment: But the best is try it.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
df_cross = pd.DataFrame(data=np.asarray(df.b) + " " + df.b[:,None], columns=df.b)
df_indicator = df_cross.applymap(lambda x: x.split()[0] in x.split()[1])
df_indicator.sum(axis=0)[lambda x: x>1].index

Out[231]: Index([u'world', u'ness'], dtype='object')
```